# How to convert a tensor to a Uint8Array array in tensorflowjs

Tags: tensorflow.js

I use `model.predict()`to output a tensor A(size:512*512*3) by tensorflow.js and then I reshape it to A.reshape(512*512*3). But now I want to convert this tensor to an array so I can use it with `three.js`. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To convert a tensor to an array, You can use

- `data()` or `dataSync()` to have a flatten typedarray

But currently the supported types are `float32`, `int32`; therefore the corresponding typedArray will be Float32Array and Int32Array. The typedarray constructors can be used to change the type of the typedarray

```js
a = tf.tensor([1, 2, 3, 4])

buffer = a.dataSync().buffer

console.log(new Uint8Array(buffer))

console.log(new Uint16Array(buffer))

console.log(new Float32Array(buffer))

// To retrieve easily uint8 type, one can cast the tensor to `int32`

a = tf.tensor([1, 2, 3, 4], undefined, 'int32')

console.log(a.dtype)

buffer = a.dataSync().buffer
console.log(new Uint8Array(buffer))
console.log(new Float32Array(buffer))
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@1.0.0"> </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is data() OK? Because dataSync() will   block the UI thread until the values are ready, which can cause performance issues.

Comment: You can use `data()`

Comment: After executing the data() function, is there any way to get the data after it is executed? Such as callback